# Retrieve list of article specifed by a locale (Directus Translation)

Tags: directus

i have an issue with filter M2M data. I want to retrieve list of article specifed by a locale (directus translation scenario)
have tried many way but these doesn't work

> articles/rows?filters[**translations.locale_id**][eq]=2
>
> articles/rows?filters[**article_translations.locale_id**][eq]=2
>
> articles/rows?filters[**locales.id**][eq]=2

here is the schemas:

1. **articles**(id, publish_date, translations: translations interface)
2. **locales**(id, name, code)
3. **articles_translations**(id, article_id: FK,locale_id: FK, title, content)

Thank for your help !
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kA0Z.png)

Additionally, in admin app I got query error when filtering by column **translations** so I think it doesn't support from admin app